# Is there a way to change the font size for road names in google direction api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am using google direction api to show the direction from point a to point b and get the screen shot. The problem i am having is when i print the page the fonts are too small to read. Is there a way to increase the font size of the streets, highways etc on the google map.

```
function initMap() {
    var markerArray = [];

    // Instantiate a directions service.
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
    //center: {lat: 40.771, lng: -73.974},
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom:15,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      gestureHandling: 'none',
      zoomControl: false,
      styles: [{elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]}]
    });

    //turn off point of interest
    var noPoi = [
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" }
        ]   
      },
      {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
        stylers: [
           { font:'42px'} 
        ]
      }
    ];

    map.setOptions({styles: noPoi});


    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    var stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Display the route between the initial start and end selections.
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(
        directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
    // Listen to change events from the start and end lists.
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(
          directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);

    //saveMapToDataUrl();
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService,
      markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
    // First, remove any existing markers from the map.
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
      markerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }

    // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using
    // WALKING directions.
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
      // markers for each step.
      if (status === 'OK') {
        document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML =
            '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        //showSteps(response, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function showSteps(directionResult, markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
    // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's infowindow.
    // Also attach the marker to an array so we can keep track of it and remove it
    // when calculating new routes.
    var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
      var marker = markerArray[i] = markerArray[i] || new google.maps.Marker;
      marker.setMap(map);
      marker.setPosition(myRoute.steps[i].start_location);
      attachInstructionText(
          stepDisplay, marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions, map);
    }
  }

  function attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, text, map) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on, containing the text
      // of the step.
      stepDisplay.setContent(text);
      stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are you creating your map?  (the tags imply the Google Maps Javascript API v3< but you didn't include a [mcve]) Did you try using a [styled map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)?  I don't know that will let you increase the size, but other than removing all the labels and adding your own, there aren't a lot of options.

Comment: @geocodezip: I have edited and added the script that i am using to generate the map.

Comment: `font` is not an allowed option for `stylers`.  Please see the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#stylers

Comment: @geocodezip: so is there no way to increase the font size for the streets and highways without creating your custom labels? i am trying to get the directions for hundreds of location and print it on paper. so default font is too small to read on paper. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned in comments, it is not currently possible through the Maps APIs to set the font size of a road name. Please see the Maps JavaScript API -- [Style Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#stylers) doc for the list of supported styles which are specifically `hue`, `lightness`, `saturation`, `gamma`, `invert_lightness`, `visibility`, `color` and `weight`.

If you are interested to have this feature, you can file this as feature request in Google Maps Platform Public Issue Tracker here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker